# Socket Host Echo not 'responding'

Tags: java, serversocket, iso8583

I am having this weird problem with the `Socket programming` I picked up recently. I understand that the Socket can be used for a `client` to communicate with a `host`. This project requires `ISO8583` as well. I already got a working code and I am modifying to work on my own testing host.

All is well and my code actually work but 1 problem I faced was that I got no *response* at all. The request sent from my computer to the host works. Host displays the correct messages and sends the response back to my computer. But I do not know why at that point, my app will just hang there. Even in debug mode, it is executing the line (which I will show you which line its executing) continuously without returning any value. This is my code below. It is quite messy and I am attempting lots of methods of trying to get a response value.

```
byte dataSmall[] = {0x00, 0x43, 0x60, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0xC0, 
            0x00, 0x00, 99, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 
            0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31};

    try {
        Socket echoSocket = new Socket("IP Address", port number);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());
         String responseLine;
         Client client = new Client(echoSocket);
        Thread reader = new Thread(client, "j8583-client");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);


            reader.start();
            os.writeObject(dataSmall);
            os.flush();

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(echoSocket.getInputStream());
            //convert ObjectInputStream object to String
            String message = (String) ois.readObject(); // this is the continuous execution
            System.out.println(message);

            System.out.println("waiting for response");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    echoSocket.getInputStream()));
            responseLine = in.readLine().toCharArray().toString();

            System.out.println("still waiting for response");
            System.out.println(responseLine);
        os.close();
        in.close();
        echoSocket.close();
        client.stop();
        reader.interrupt();
```

I have tried **.readObject()** and **.readLine()** hopefully to get the response output and both perform the same problem. Executing with no end to it. Unfortunately I am out of ideas on how I should approach this. It is very important that I get the response from my test host. So I appreciate any help you guys can give. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the server you're talking to isn't written in Java or doesn't use Object Serialization, this code cannot possibly work. I don't see any reason here to use Object streams. Try it with the actual socket streams.

Comment: Yea, I was trying alternatives. So the I tried `Object Serialization` it is not the method I would choose to use. Actual socket streams works nicely, but I still cannot receive the response as the **.readLine()** code will simply hang there.

Comment: @MelvinLai That would indicate that the peer isn't sending lines. You don't seem to have any clue about the application protocol. You need to know that before you start coding.

Answer (score 1):

ISO8583 messaging is usually done in asynchronous mode, and the way to read/write ISO messages is to put the length of the message first, encoded as a 16-bit unsigned integer.

So first you need to put your ISO message in a byte buffer, measure it, then write that length, and then the message (and flush the stream).

To read the response, first you read 2 bytes, interpret those as a 16-bit unsigned integer, then create a buffer of that size and read the rest of the message. You need a dedicated thread to read responses continuously and pass them to some other worker for parsing and processing.

Answer (score -2):

If the same code works on a different host and NOT on yours then you may need to look for port (s) contention. Whenever a client connection is created, an arbitary port is opened on the server to communicate with the client. Your firewall/antivirus may be blocking it and hence you are not able to send the response back.

Comment: Completely incorrect. The accepted socket uses the same local port number as the listening socket. The question of port contention does not arise. If the client can connect, he can communicate.

Comment: Agreed. This is not the only platform I am using to connect. I have done an iOS device. It is using the same `InputStream` and `OutputStream` like what I found in Java. But I can get a response on my iOS but not on my Java, soon I would use it for Android but for now I am testing on Java since the source code I found is a *Java Project*.